# When is the StoreGeneratedPattern attribute added to a property in the ssdl? (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, diagram, designer, edmx, ssdl

When I create a new diagram and "Update model from database", the StoreGeneratedPattern attribute gets added to some primary key properties, but not all of them. What criteria does the designer use to decide whether to add this or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it was because my database was not consistent. It appears to add the attribute to any primary key that is an identity column.